# File structure for publishing firefox addon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, manifest

I'm trying to publish a firefox addon, but I'm getting an error:

`Error: "/background" is in an unsupported format`

My first thought was that maybe it's an issue with me migrating from manifest v2 to v3, but since it says "/background" I figured maybe I'm supposed to have a background folder or something. If that's the case, are there any other changes I need to make for my file strucutre? If not, what's the issue here?

Here is my current file structure:

```
┣ .vscode
 ┃ ┗ settings.json
 ┣ css
 ┃ ┣ options.css
 ┃ ┗ popup.css
 ┣ html
 ┃ ┣ options.html
 ┃ ┗ popup.html
 ┣ icons
 ┃ ┣ 128
 ┃ ┃ ┣ error.png
 ┃ ┃ ┣ operational.png
 ┃ ┃ ┗ warning.png
 ┃ ┣ feather
 ┃ ┃ ┣ help-circle.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ refresh-cw.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┗ settings.svg
 ┃ ┣ .DS_Store
 ┃ ┣ green_icon.png
 ┃ ┣ red_icon.png
 ┃ ┗ yellow_icon.png
 ┣ js
 ┃ ┣ node_modules
 ┃ ┃ ┣ @types
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ firefox-webext-browser
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ LICENSE
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ README.md
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ index.d.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ package.json
 ┃ ┃ ┗ .package-lock.json
 ┃ ┣ common.js
 ┃ ┣ options.js
 ┃ ┣ package-lock.json
 ┃ ┣ package.json
 ┃ ┣ popup.js
 ┃ ┗ test.js
 ┣ .DS_Store
 ┣ LICENSE
 ┣ README.md
 ┣ jsconfig.json
 ┗ manifest.json
```

And here is my current `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "GPTstatus",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "gptstatus@example.org"
    }
  },

  "description": "A browser extension that changes its icon depending on the status of ChatGPT.",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/Zev18/gptstatus",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/128/operational.png"
  },

  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/128/operational.png",
    "default_title": "GPTstatus",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "js/common.js"
  },

  "options_ui": {
    "page": "html/options.html",
    "browser_style": true
  },

  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"]
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Firefox doesn't support service_worker yet, probably. Use `scripts` array instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I was told that I had to use service_worker for manifest v3 and that firefox supports v3 now. Do chrome and firefox support different variants of manifest v3?

Comment: Yes. Firefox is different, it allows DOM in the background script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use `scripts` instead of `service_worker`, as mentioned by wOxxOm in their comment. Just putting this here so I can mark the question as answered.